# SPFx -Error when use last version of Office-UI-React with SPFX 1.4.0

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, react, office-ui-fabric-react

I want to use last version of Office-UI-React with SharePoint Framework v 1.4.0 with TypeScript Version 2.2.2.

When i install last version office-UI-React have following error:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the absence of an actual question, I assume your question is "how do I fix the error."  I've tried upgrading office-ui-fabric-react (OUFR) independently of the Yeoman Generator and I believe it can be done, but I chose to abandon that route.

Microsoft states the following on [this page](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/use-fabric-react-components):

> Note
>
> With the current release of the SharePoint Framework, we recommend
>   that you use the Office UI Fabric and Fabric React that ships with the
>   generator. We do not recommend that you update the Office UI Fabric
>   and Fabric React packages independently because that might conflict
>   with the already available version in SharePoint, and as a result,
>   your web part may fail to function as expected.

In my use case the benefits of new features in the latest OUFR package did not outweigh the cost of managing a unique/unsupported project dependency tree.